# Access violation exception from Delphi's Supports -> QueryInterface

Tags: delphi, access-violation, queryinterface

I have the following piece of code:

```
  for i := 0 to FControlList.Count - 1 do
      if Supports(IMyControl(FControlList[i]), IMyControlEx) then
      begin
        MyControlEx := IMyControl(FControlList[i]) as IMyControlEx;
        MyControlEx.DoYourMagic(Self, SomeData);
      end;
```

This code is called many times during my application execution, but in some specific cases it fails inside the Supports() method. And more specifically - it seems to fall inside the QueryInterface() call within the Supports() method.

I checked that FControlList is not nil and FControlList[i] is not nil and it still happens.

Any idea will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Can you remove the cast to IMyControl in the Supports call? What is FControlList, a IInterfaceList?

Comment: Also note that TControl can have their own life cycle management, even if they are subclasses of TInterfacedPersistent they do not use reference counting. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182612

Comment: It is just because TInterfacedPersistent doesn't use reference counting. Otherwise TInterfacedObject were used.

Comment: Supports requires a GUID to be defined for the interface, I'm assuming you've done so for IMyControlEx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if `FControlList[I]` is not `nil`, that doesn't mean it points to valid data. The underlying object instance may have been freed already.

I also suggest to remove the type cast to `IMyControl`. `Supports` can take objects and interfaces as parameter, even if they are `nil`, and produce the desired result.

In addition you may consider using this way of calling `supports` for your convinience and readabilty of the code:

```
if Supports(FControlList[i], IMyControlEx, MyControlEx) then
begin
  MyControlEx.DoYourMagic(Self, SomeData);
end;
```

Comment: Looks like you're right and indeed it has some freed data.
The problem is very complicated and I haven't solved it yet, but still - that's the answer. Thanks!